# Python Script to fill specific column on Power Bi

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way on Power Bi to populate a specific column with values **using a Python Script**? For example, I want to calculate the number of days between the start date and end date in this table:

[image: Power Bi Table].

Comment: Is there a need to do it in Python? M/Power Query will do this Duration.Days([Date1] - [Date2])

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to 'Edit Queries`
2. A dialog box with your table will open, then click `Run Python Script`
3. Enter the below code and press `OK`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Remaining Days'] = pd.to_datetime( df['Contract End Date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Contract Start Date'])
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately, the error is  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str', even though "Contract Start Date" and "Contract End Date" are both type date

Comment: This ought to be a type error and the column values are beig read as `string`, kindly check the update. Hope it works.

Comment: How do I change them as a Date? I already made the changes in the table but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: df['Contract End Date']  = pd.to_datetime( df['Contract End Date'])  , same for the other column